# Correct approach to make UI only in code, without XAML?

Tags: xaml, uno-platform

I'm trying to develop Uno apps in linux (MX-linux) using in VS code. I wish to make it without using XAML. Creating the repository with the templates, I proceed to delete the `MainPage.xaml` file, and replace the `InitializeComponent();` with my code of UI.

While this works fairly well in `Skia.Gtk` platform, the `Wasm` build fails as it is unable to find `MainPage.xaml` file.

Here is the beginning portion of the large log while building

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
MSBUILD : error : Generation failed: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Generation failed for Uno.UI.SourceGenerators.XamlGenerator.XamlCodeGenerator. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to parse file /home/Coding/UnoPrac/UnoPrac.Shared/MainPage.xaml)
```

So my question is, am I approaching this the correct way? Sure, I can make the xaml file to just contain the `<Page..>` element and it works for some platforms, but is it just possible to force Uno to ignore the xaml files if not present?

**EDIT:** I tested it on windows as well. It seems that the `Skia.Gtk` platform is unique in that it can run without any of the xaml files, provided the suitable code-behind is present for every `InitializeComponent()` method in `*.xaml.cs` files.

I deleted the `App.xaml` file and added this snippet in place of `InitializeComponent()` method in `App.xaml.cs` file

```cs
this.Resources = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.XamlControlsResources();
```

Similarly, I deleted the `MainPage.xaml` file and added this in place of `InitializeComponent()` method in `App.xaml.cs` file

```cs
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        Button nextPage = new Button() { Content = "Next" };
        TextBlock block = new TextBlock() { Text = "Welcome to Uno" };
        public MainPage()
        {
            //this.InitializeComponent();
            Content = new Grid() { Children = { block, nextPage } };
        }
    }
```

While this setup works flawlessly in the `Skia.Gtk` platform, it doesn't work with anything else I tested: UWP, Android and Wasm.

On keeping the xaml files with the empty `<Page>` element, the Android platform app does work successfully, while the UWP encounters a runtime error, and the Wasm app runs but the Page is blank (i.e no component appears).

If the code used for the Gtk platform is able to ignore the xaml files, is there any equivalent for the other platforms in Uno? Or is this approach not possible at all?

Comment: Worth noting that whilst you can do this just to see if it works, making an actually functional app with it will become problematic as you lose support for DataTemplates, styling, compiled bindings and a few other things that either make development much faster or actually improve performance.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake It may become a bit more tedious, but I feel it won't be that big a deal and certainly not impossible. I've been developing in Xamarin for a while and AFAIK all the xaml you can type can be converted into code-behind (and it is done implicitly while building). I feel that instead of waiting for a free tool bundled with XAML support to come for Linux development, It is better to go with the approach flutter went with, and create UI in code. I understand your point, that XAML provides a really comfortable abstraction, and I'm ready to come out of that comfort zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the needed change. I initially thought the issue was in the individual platforms, but now I understand the only reason the `Skia.Gtk` port was running, unlike the other platforms, was because the build errors were failing silently in it.

To solve the issue, all dependency on any xaml file is to be removed In the `*.Shared.projitems`. According to my testing, the `App.xaml` itself can be removed and replaced according to the question and it will run perfectly fine on Android, Linux(Skia.Gtk) and WebAssembly. However, the UWP has some internal dependency on the `App.xaml` file so in the end I couldn't remove it. But, on removing the references of all the other `xaml` files, All ports that I tested (UWP, Android, Skia.Gtk and WebAssembly) are running without issue.

Just for the sake of completeness, I'll include my edited `*.Shared.projitems` below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <HasSharedItems>true</HasSharedItems>
    <SharedGUID>6279c845-92f8-4333-ab99-3d213163593c</SharedGUID>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <Import_RootNamespace>UnoPrac</Import_RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)App.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*.cs"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Assets\SharedAssets.md" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PRIResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Strings\en\Resources.resw" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Oh and the reason I got a "blank" page in the Wasm app was simply because the background was white, along with all the components on it. So I only needed to set the background of the page as black.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some leftover traces of the `MainPage.xaml` in the `bin` or `obj` folders of the WASM project. Open the solution folder in VS Code and search for `MainPage.xaml` everywhere. Make sure to remove the areas where the file is referenced. After that the build should work again.